# Grails 3.1 Testing Controllers as Integration

Tags: grails, integration-testing, grails-3.1

I'm having problems with integration test about controllers with Grails 3 (more specific Grails 3.1.3).

As the documentation said, now testing controllers is recommended to create a Geb functional test, but is a hard work to transform all the controller test that I have to Geb.

I've tried to transform test wiht annotation `@Integration` and extend `GebSpec`.

The first problem I encountered is to mock GrailsWeb, but with `GrailsWebMockUtil.bindMockWebRequest(ctx)` I resolved it (being `ctx` and object of type `WebApplicationContext`).
Now, the problem is when the controller render some content or redirect to another action/controller. Until now, I solved this overriding render or redirect method, in the setupSpec phase:

```
controller.metaClass.redirect = { Map map ->
    redirectMap = map
}

controller.metaClass.render = { Map map ->
    renderMap = map
}
```

But this doesn't work, because when you try to obtain `renderMap` or `redirectMap` in `then` or `expect` phase in test, these are empty.

Does anyone know what could be the solution?

**EDIT (to clarify):**

I edit my question to clarify the problem:

Thank you very much for your response @JeffScottBrown. As I mentioned, this workaround is to solve the problems with controller test as integration test in Grails 3, trying to transform all the test we had in Grails 2.x. 
I know that the best solution is to make it as unit test or functional test, but I want to know if there is an "easy" solution to keep it as in version Grails 2.x.

I attached I small [project](https://github.com/MiguelAngel82/integrationTestController) that shows what I want to do. In this project there is Controller with two actions. One action renders a template and another action renders a view. 
In the test, if I check the action that renders the template, the `modelAndView` object is empty. This is the reason why I override the `render` and `redirect` as I showed.

Comment: You should not be calling `bindMockWebRequest` from an integration test.

Comment: "As the documentation said, now testing controllers is recommended to create a Geb functional test" - it is recommended that you create a Geb test if you want to write a functional test.  Unit tests should still be written as unit tests, which would not involve Geb.

Comment: You should not be doing something like `controller.metaClass.redirect = { ... }` in an integration test.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @JeffScottBrown. As I mentioned, this workaround is to solve the problems with controller test as integration test in Grails 3, trying to transform all the test we had in Grails 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things in your integration test that are not valid or not a good idea in an integration test.  I don't know if you are really asking how to write integration tests in general, or how to test the scenario in your sample app in particular.  The way to test the scenario in your sample app is with a unit test.

```
// src/test/groovy/integrationtestcontroller/TestControllerSpec.groovy
package integrationtestcontroller

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(TestController)
class TestControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "render the template"() {
        when:
        controller.index()

        then:
        response.text == '<span>The model rendered is: parameterOne: value of parameter one - parameterTwo: value of parameter two</span>'
    }

    void "render the view"() {
        when:
        controller.renderView()

        then:
        view == '/test/testView'
        model.parameterOne == 'value of parameter one'
        model.parameterTwo == 'value of parameter two'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much again for your response ;)
I have a question about the code you have showed, is it possible to access to `modelAndView` object in the first test (where the render of a template is made)? I think this is the key of my original question.
Thanks a lot!